# Fetching Data in ReactJs Before Any Rendering

Tags: reactjs

I know this title seems a duplicate of many other questions but I'm looking for a specific **YES or NO answer** for my question which I haven't come across in all the posts I have seen here.

I'm working on a school app `admin dashboard` where I have all the options you could imagine an admin of such app could have.

Now when I enter any of these `routes` I want to do so many `fetching` of different types of data.
Using `useEffect` seems the obvious solution but it doesn't run until the rendering part is over which results in many `undefined` variables.

The solutions I've seen in other posts were:

- Using *conditional rendering* - which solves nothing because I want to view the data on the first render.
- Fetching all the requested data on `Parent Component` then passing the data as a `prop`. The problem with this solution is that it requires the `dashboard` code to be **super complex** because it will technically have all the fetching in the application inside one file! which is going to create a **big, complicated and error-prone** codebase.

So my the question boils down to: Is there any **other way** to fetch and view data on the first render? And if there is one what it is? And if there isn't then what is the best solution to deal with this in react? Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at react router's loader? https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/loader

Comment: Did you use react router Library? It will solve your problem.

Comment: @p7dxb it does seem to be a good solution however it doesn't help if the fetching operation depends on some other props passed from another component. e.g. I want to pass the `school id` to some route as a prop then I wouldn't be able to do it.

Comment: I believe you can use params in the loader request. In your case the `school id`

Comment: @p7dxb Oh yea you're right. You can post your answer and I'll give it an accepted answer. Do you know of any other possible ways to deal with this issue tho?

Comment: None that I know of really. Is there something that the loader isn't doing for you I'm missing?

Comment: @p7dxb It's just that the app router file will get bigger as the application grows. it seems there's no way I could get around this with no disadvantages.

Comment: Yeah, its a good point. I added a small example of importing the loader function to my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution

- From react-router docs you can use [loader](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/loader)

> Each route can define a "loader" function to provide data to the route element before it renders.

- You can then use this data in the component using [use-loader-data](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-loader-data)

#### Keeping it clean

- You can put the loader functions in your relevant component file and then import to your router

Example for "event" data:

```
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";
import EventDetailPage, {
  loader as eventDetailsLoader,
} from "./pages/EventDetailPage";

//Create router
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <RootLayout />,
    errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
    children: [
      { index: true, element: <HomePage /> },
      {
        path: "events",
        element: <EventsRootLayout />,
        children: [
          {
            index: true,
            element: <EventsPage />,
            loader: eventsLoader,
          },
          {
            path: ":eventID",
            loader: eventDetailsLoader,
            element: <EventDetailPage />,
          },
```

```
import { json, useLoaderData, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import EventItem from "../components/EventItem";

function EventDetailPage() {
  const params = useParams();
  const data = useLoaderData();

  return <EventItem event={data.event} />;
}

export default EventDetailPage;

export async function loader({ request, params }) {
  const id = params.eventID;
  const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/events/" + id);

  if (!response.ok) {
    throw json({ message: "Could not fetch details" }, { status: 500 });
  } else {
    return response;
  }
}
```